# Any advice to remove the buzzer?

Tags: buzzer

This is the control panel of laundry unit. The black plastic objects soldered to the board are buzzers right? Can I disconnect soldered legs via careful pliers? I don’t have a soldering iron. Only by my best guess are those even the buzzers, I’ll just power back on and check I suppose.[image]

Comment: Does the front of the device have an obvious hole for the sound output? You might verify that by just placing a piece of tape over the hole then run a cycle and listen for a muffled buzzer sound. If you are just looking to reduce the sound level that may be enough.

Comment: That might be a vibration sensor. Show us a picture of the whole board. Post the picture, not a screen grab of the picture in the editor!

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to achieve? Stop the buzzer from making a sound when your laundry is finished?

Note that there is a small risk that removing the buzzer does some damage (for example if the driver is a constant current driver, then voltage might increase too high).

The component you show hasn't the most typical format of a buzzer, but it's seems still rather likely that it is one (to be sure, wait for confirmation from someone else, or send images of the whole board so we can check nothing else can be a buzzer).

If all you want to do is silence the buzzer, then there is no need to remove it entirely : it's enough to cut one of the leads (the vertical one on the front should be easy to cut with cutting pliers).

Comment: Removing sound, yes it’s super loud and annoying and waiting it out never stops it. I’ll try the tape first thanks guys.